# SQL Server 2012 Tabular model project in Visual Studio 2010? SSDT

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I've downloaded a shell version of Visual Studio 2012/SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) which allows me to create Analysis Services Tabular Models but because it is a shell (integrated) version it only allows for a small amount of functionality.

I have a full professional edition of visual studio 2010 and have installed SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) but there is no business intelligence project templates available.

Will I need to purchase visual studio 2012 to get this full functionality or is there a way I can do it within the visual studio 2010 environment?

The SQL Server is 2012

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> You can install SQL Server Data Tools on Visual Studio 2010
>   Professional, Premium, or Ultimate Edition with Visual Studio 2010
>   SP1.

You can find the link to download Visual Studio 2010 SP1 on the MSDN page (I don't like linking directly to downloads on SO since people can edit the links.)

Also, according to [this other MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027),

> ```
> Projects and DACPACs are fully compatible across shells. 
> Please download the toolset for VS2012 ...
> ```

Again, a link to SSDT 2012 is on the site. You might want to uninstall your integrated shell version just to get a clean binding with your existing VS2010 install.

**UPDATE**

Please also read [James Serra's blog about the BI templates for Visual STudio 2012](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2013/03/visual-studio-2012-now-supports-bi/) coming in a separate install from SSDT, which also includes a link to that install.

Comment: Thanks for that. I downloaded the SP1 for VS2010 previously, tried uninstalling VS2012 then installed the SSDT 2012 but still to no avail, I have tried a few other things but can't seem to get it working

Comment: Try downloading this, it says it's for VS2012 but as with all the other literature that appears to be backwards-compatible: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843